# How do I calculate the number of the key of a specific property from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, oop, ecmascript-6, frontend

Image I have a

```
const events: {
        '12327ae260fe9431': {
          eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR',
          key: '12327ae260fe9431',
          severity: 'ERROR',
          timestamp: 1542199782975,
          title: 'Link went down unexpectedly',
        },
        '62d29fab77bddd7': {
          eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR',
          key: '62d29fab77bddd7',
          severity: 'ERROR',
          timestamp: 1542199783055,
          title: 'Link went down unexpectedly',
        },
      },
```

I want to calculate the total severity and construct a `severityCounts` object like this

```
 severityCounts: {
        CRITICAL: 0,
        ERROR: 2,
        INFO: 0,
        WARNING: 0,
      }
```

and I have access to `Lodash`. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Start small...first figure out how to iterate through the object and access each `severity`. Once you get there it's fairly easy to add 1 to a counter for that type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group the data by `severity`, get the length and assign all information to a single object.

```js
var data = { '12327ae260fe9431': { eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR', key: '12327ae260fe9431', severity: 'ERROR', timestamp: 1542199782975, title: 'Link went down unexpectedly' }, '62d29fab77bddd7': { eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR', key: '62d29fab77bddd7', severity: 'ERROR', timestamp: 1542199783055, title: 'Link went down unexpectedly' } },
    result = _.assign(
        { CRITICAL: 0, ERROR: 0, INFO: 0, WARNING: 0 },
        ..._(data)
            .values()
            .groupBy('severity')
            .map(({ length }, key) => ({ [key]: length }))
            .value()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.values()` to generate an array of all your values and then using `array#reduce` you can create an object with a count of each `severity` count.

```js
const events = { '12327ae260fe9431': { eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR', key: '12327ae260fe9431', severity: 'ERROR', timestamp: 1542199782975, title: 'Link went down unexpectedly', }, '62d29fab77bddd7': { eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR', key: '62d29fab77bddd7',severity: 'ERROR', timestamp: 1542199783055, title: 'Link went down unexpectedly', }, },
      severityCounts = Object.values(events).reduce((r, {severity}) => {
        r[severity] = ( r[severity] || 0 ) + 1;
        return r;
      },{ CRITICAL: 0, ERROR: 0, INFO: 0, WARNING: 0});
console.log(severityCounts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please always post your attempt in OP before asking so that we get to know where you are stuck

You can loop through the object using `for .. of` and increment counter like below. No need for `lodash`

```js
const events = {
        '12327ae260fe9431': {
          eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR',
          key: '12327ae260fe9431',
          severity: 'ERROR',
          timestamp: 1542199782975,
          title: 'Link went down unexpectedly',
        },
        '62d29fab77bddd7': {
          eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR',
          key: '62d29fab77bddd7',
          severity: 'ERROR',
          timestamp: 1542199783055,
          title: 'Link went down unexpectedly',
        },
        '62d29fab77bddd71': {
          eventType: 'DEVICE_LINK_ERR',
          key: '62d29fab77bddd7',
          severity: 'INFO',
          timestamp: 1542199783055,
          title: 'Link went down unexpectedly',
        }
      }

let severityCounts = { CRITICAL: 0, ERROR: 0, INFO: 0, WARNING: 0 }

for(let { severity } of Object.values(events)) {
  severityCounts[severity] = severityCounts[severity] || 0
  severityCounts[severity]++
}

console.log(severityCounts)
```